# Draftsight / AutoCAD - How to show/hide Multiple Layers @ the Same Time?

Tags: autocad

Is there a way to show/hide multiple layers @ the same time?

For example, I have layers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...
**Assume** there is a button if you press. layer 2, 4 & 5 are visible. The others are hidden.

If you wonder why, I have a complex drawing of a machine. The technician might not want to show all the components in that drawing before he prints the drawings. So I want to give him a quick method to accomplish that. One click will show & hide bunch of layers (Edit: instead of selecting one by one. He will not know which layer is which).

Comment: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-architecture/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Architecture/files/GUID-ACA0470C-989F-4EB6-957F-E74797F1177B-htm.html

Comment: nice! We have Draftsight. I will search the document for Group Layer.

Comment: Another two options at your disposal are: 1. Using a https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-DB55FE5C-6B51-40AE-AE3D-4C3A28ADC5D9-htm.html (script) to set the layer states (clue there :) ) and 2. Using the https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-3E0F662B-226F-4A27-B5BB-D15252CC994C-htm.html (Layer States Manager).